# Combining values in ASP.Net Routes for MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Can anyone suggest a way to accomplish the following in ASP.Net Routing (for MVC 3)?

I want to have URLs where the value which determines the controller is actually part of the id for the page:

```
/{id}-{controller}/{action}/{further-values}
```

But I need the id value to include the value used for the controller as well, so in the above if we have the following URL:

```
/chelsea-football-team/view/2010-2011
```

I want the {id} value to, ideally, be "chelsea-football-team", the controller to be "football-team", the action to be "view" and the additional value to be "2010-2011".

I have no issues having several routes with the controller value hard coded into the route definition, but I need to be able to have several controller values.

I know that I can simply combine the values in the controller, but that adds a lot of additional, repeated code - so is this accomplishable in any other way?

Why do I want to do this?  Because I need to have the team name in full, but part of the team name will always match the controller name so why not combine them in the route?

Comment: Shouldn't `{further-values}` be `{*furtherValues}`? Since you can't create a hyphenated argument in your action method?

Comment: Its just a generic representation of what Im after, not actually working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want the {id} value to, ideally, be "chelsea-football-team", the controller to be "football-team", the action to be "view" and the additional value to be "2010-2011".

```
...MapRoute(null, "{id}/{action}/{*furtherValues}", 
        new {
            controller = "FootballTeam",
        });
```

**Update after comment 1**

You can't combine route parameters in a URL such that a single parameter represents both a variable (id) and a controller, using the standard routing implementation. If you want the id to be "chelsea-football-team", that has to be a self-contained route parameter. You can't combine it in a way that MVC extracts the controller name from the id.

To meet this requirement, you may have to create a custom RouteBase implementation:

```
public class MyCustomRoutingPattern : RouteBase
{
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // do your coding and return an instance of RouteData
    }
}
```

You would then use it like so:

```
routes.Add(new MyCustomRoutingPattern(
    "{id}/{action}/{*furtherValues}"));
```

Your RouteBase implementation can then extract the controller from the id parameter. The Pro ASP.NET MVC3 Framework book by Steve Sanderson and Adam Freeman has a section on how to override the RouteBase class.

Comment: Nope, because that limits me to one single controller, when I require the ability to define or hint at the controller used in the url.  Thanks for the answer tho :)